# Sprockets::FileNotFound in StaticPages#home

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sprockets

i'm working on Michael Hartl's ruby on rails tutorial and i've run into a problem that i haven't been able to fix for days.

when trying to load the page, chrome reads:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in StaticPages#home
Showing /Users/azimmer/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #7 raised:

couldn't find file 'jquery'
  (in /Users/azimmer/rails_projects/sample_app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:13)
Extracted source (around line #7):
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

      <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                             "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
      <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
      </head>

Rails.root: /Users/azimmer/rails_projects/sample_app
```

here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.3.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'
gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'

end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

and here is my application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                           "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

my application.js file is totally untouched.  i have tried everything from adding gem rubyracer, to editing the runtimes.rb file in execjs recommended on another thread.  i'm considering just starting over from scratch in order to get everything to work, at least in that case i would relearn a lot of what i've learned, but i'm hoping someone can at least help me figure out what is going on here.

thanks a bunch for your help!

cheers,
alex

EDIT

it works if i change the line from

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

to

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :default, "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

could anyone explain what this means?  and how making that change might affect my application in a negative way?  thank you for the help!

Comment: i confirm, that's work  with _:default_ instead of _application_

Comment: `npm install` worked out for me as advised below by @Nejweti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following lines to the app/assets/javascripts/application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Also make sure that you have run `bundle install`.

After this run `bundle show jquery-rails` to verify that gem was successfully installed.

**EDIT**

Update your Gemfile as below:
`jquery-rails` and few other gems required in all the environments were listed under `test` group so you couldn't access them in development environment.
Correct the Gemfile as below:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.3.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
end
```

After this `bundle update` and `bundle install`. You should be good to go.

Comment: those lines were already in there and i've been running bundle update and install a lot to try to see if different versions people suggested would fix the problem, but to no avail.  when i put
    'bundle show jquery-rails'
i get 
     '/Users/azimmer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/jquery-rails-2.3.0'
and i get the same error in chrome(or any other browser).  i'm wondering if its a problem with my path or asset pipeline?

Comment: @user3450489 Had a good look at the Gemfile. See my updated answer in EDIT section.

Comment: that did it!  thank you so much that was super helpful.  now i'll know for the future.

Comment: I was missing `jquery-rails`. Thanks Kirti! :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, the problem was not related to the existing gems but rather with the cached version of them.

The following steps solved the issue for me:

1. Specify the actual versions for the affected gems
2. Clean the asset pipeline by doing `rake assets:clean`
3. Clean your browser's cache
4. Start the server again

This process won't be the same for everyone as the issue here is tied to the cached version of the gems, as I've already mentioned.

At least it should help to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rails 5. you need to install node.js using `npm install`, so that rails install the frontend requirments automatically for us. This solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you @Nejweti I have been trying to solve this for days, the above solutions didn't work for my case and I believe may not work for newer versions of rails.

Answer (score 0):

Add commands /config/initialize/assets

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
```